# switch oscillation on flutter

Tags: toggle, flutter

it's my first question here, I'm newbi. I have an issue with switch on flutter.

I did this simple code like the example but in a certain moment, when I switch quickely, the switch begin to oscillate. how can I fix this problem? thank you

```
bool _switchValue = false;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return new Scaffold(
  body: new Container(
    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
    child: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
         new Switch(
          value: _switchValue,
          onChanged: (bool value) { setState(() {
            _switchValue = value;
              }
            );
          },
        )
      ],
     )
   )
 );
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean oscillate? Your code looks right as far as I can tell. You may want to try running your app in release mode to see if you can still reproduce the problem, as debug mode tends to be a lot slower and that may partly explain the behaviour. See [this](https://flutter.io/faq/#my-app-has-a-slow-mode-bannerribbon-in-the-upper-right-why-am-i-seeing-that)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply I will try that. the switch bounced from right to left alone after a manual quick switch. the issue is due to the presence of ( _switchValue = value; ) if I delete this ligne , the oscillation is remove but the switch can't return two states

Comment: Just tried in release mode, no change

Comment: hmm. Well just to satisfy my curiosity, is this on a real device or on the simulator? It still sounds like a timing issue to me unless someone can see something wrong the code I'm missing, but I can't reproduce it on my phone. Also - does it only oscillate when you're still tapping it? Because that might just be expected behaviour (every time you tap it, even if the animation hasn't finished, it should technically switch to the other state). i.e. if you tap it 5 times very quickly, does it eventually end up at the expected state (different than the first state)?

Comment: No problems when I tap on it repeatly, I tried the release mode on my device. Try a partial quick switch mouvement to reproduce the issue ( it can be come of an indeterminate state of the switch combine to a quick mouvement conditions ?)

Comment: Was you able to solve this already?
I'm facing the same Issue. Just tried a dozen approaches but with no success.The problem only occurs to me when I swap the switch very rapidly in a 45 degree angle from the switch direction and it only happens on real devices. Looks like a bug in the Android user interface(?). Wondering if it also happens on iOS.

Comment: no solutions for me actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug that is fixed with an update.

The bug is discussed here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17773

Fix commit is here if you wish to fix it for your self by editing the `packages/flutter/lib/src/material/toggleable.dart` file: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/17821